# Beamer: margins in metropolis theme when combined with infolines

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I am using the metropolis theme and I want to combine it with

```
\useoutertheme{infolines}
```

It works nicely except of the following: the margins are affected in a way that I don't like. So my question is: can I combine infolines with metropolis but still keep the original margins?

Below is a minimal working example. To make sense, one needs to compare the compilations with the line `\useoutertheme{infolines}` commented and uncommented.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

%\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title[Title]{A descriptive Title}
\author[F]{First Author, Second Author, Third Author}
\institute[U]{University of} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `infolines` theme sets margins to `1em`. You can restore the default margins via:

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1cm,text margin right=1cm}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly! I am tempted to ask some other stuff but let's leave it for another question :)!